# Como aplicar clausula where en JPA

Tags: java, api, jpa

estoy comenzando con JPA en netbeans y me propuse crear un pequeño mantenedor de un curso(escuela). Me encontré con un problema al obtener un grupo de alumnos según el curso, no he dado cómo introducir la clausula "where" o algún agrupador para guardar los registros en una lista:

```
 public List<Alumno> alumnos(String curso){
    List<Alumno> a = ejbFacade.findAll();
    return  a;
}
```

Alguien me podria dar una idea de como hacerlo?

Comment: Por favor muestra la relación entre tus entidades `Alumno` y `Curso`. Con eso podremos a ayudarte a escribir el query en JPQL apropiado.

Answer (score -1):

```
Query query = entitymanager.createQuery("select * from alumnos where nombre = :nombre");
query.setParameter("nombre", 'Jose');
List<String> list=query.getResultList();
```

Otra manera sería crear con @NamedQuery, el query lo defines en la entidad

```
@Entity
@Tabel("alumnos")
@NameQuery("select * from alumnos where nombre = :nombre", name="buscar por nombre")// es un ejemplo
pulic class Alumno{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   private Long id;

  @Column
  private String nombre;

}
```

y despues puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
Query query = entitymanager.createNamedQuery("buscar por nombre"); 
query.setParameter("nombre", 'Jose');
List<String> list=query.getResultList();
```